# Dropbox: Ubuntu 14.04, Cinnamon, Nemo

Tags: 14.04, dropbox, cinnamon, nemo

I cant link Dropbox with Nemo. I uninstalled Nautilus, installed dropbox then installed nemo-dropbox, but it doesn't work.

These are the steps I've done:

1: sudo apt-get install cinnamon
2: restart and log into cinnamon
3: sudo apt-get purge nautilus
4: sudo apt-get autoremove nautilus
5: download and install [Dropbox for Ubuntu x64](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_2015.02.12_amd64.deb)
6: sudo apt-get install nemo-dropbox
7: run dropbox

problem: dropbox folder in nemo, doesn't have the "dropbox" menu when I right click, and icons dont have dropbox symbols (syncing or synced)

Comment: Please edit your answer showing steps you have did and what is the error?

Comment: Is it more understandable now?

Comment: Are you sure that menu is installed with the `nemo-dropbox` package? I have used this package in various systems with 14.04 and 15.04 and it never created such menu.

Answer (score 0):

The dropbox integration you describe is dependent on the package `nemo-python` which is, as far as I know, not part of the ubuntu repositories.
Same goes for integration with the ownCloud desktop client, for example.

Compared to Linux Mint, the Ubuntu repos still miss some packages (like `nemo-preview` and aforementioned `nemo-python`). Even on 15.10 this does not work out-of-the box.

If you can find a version of `nemo-python` (e.g. in a PPA somewhere) your chances are much higher of getting it to work.